# repost No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\xampp\htdocs\frix\checkcon.php on line 2

Tags: php

when i run it on the browser given the url localhost/foldername/checkcon.php. it always post the error

here is my code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("192.168.1.130","root","color","inventory1");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblemployee");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['Employee_ID'] . " " . $row['Employee_Name'];
echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: mysqli_connect("192.168.1.130","root","color","inventory1"); are you using color password for root user

Comment: Are external connections allowed on `192.168.1.130`

Comment: This may happen due to a port block, also check your mysql credentials.

Comment: harish yes Im using color as my password to SQLyog Ultimate MYSQL GUI

Comment: Gaurav Bhor - where can I check the MYSQL credentials?

Comment: Thank you to all who gave their suggestions. appreciated them much.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL server probably allows connections only from localhost. So if your database is on the same machine as that script is, change the ip from mysqli_connect to 127.0.0.1, or reconfigure your MySQL to allow connections from outside of localhost.

Comment: in my SQLyog MYSQL GUI that host address is 192.168.1.130. what must be the problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are putting right credentials.especially

```
mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd")
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most probably caused by **Firewall**. Try disabling it and try again.

If this doesn't work...
Try replacing your IP Address with **`localhost`** or **`127.0.0.1`**(loopback address) on your **`mysqli connect`** statement.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","color","inventory1");
```

Comment: if I will change the ip address to localhost it will post this error Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\frix\checkcon.php on line 2

Comment: the MYSQL host address in my SQLyog MYSQL GUI is 192.168.1.130 that's why I used it as host.